# add a span tag inside h2 tag jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add a span tag inside every h2 tags

my problem is im having an anchor tag inside h2 tag like this

```
<h2><a href=#">something</a></h2>
```

I have tried this code

```
$('h2').wrappInner('<span />');
```

It is wrapping span tage before the anchor tag like

```
<h2><span><a href="#">something</a></span></h2>
```

What i want is this:

```
<h2><span></span><a href="#">something</a></h2>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
$('h2').prepend('<span />');
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/k7vPM/).

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$('h2').prepend('<span />');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('h2').prepend('<span />');
```